# New to Auto Layout - why isn't my view appearing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have the following code:

```
        UITextField *loginBox = [[UITextField alloc] init];
        loginBox.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        [self.view addSubview:loginBox];

        NSLayoutConstraint *horizontalPlacementConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:loginBox attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
        [self.view addConstraint:horizontalPlacementConstraint];

        NSLayoutConstraint *verticalPlacementConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:loginBox attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
        [self.view addConstraint:verticalPlacementConstraint];

        NSLayoutConstraint *widthConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:loginBox attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:0 toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:100];
        [self.view addConstraint:widthConstraint];
```

(Not possible to do in IB.)

But when I load the view, it never shows the textfield. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UITextField` is definitly there and properly placed at `0, 0`.
You probably just can't see it. Set your `borderStyle` or something similar:

```
loginBox.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
```

Answer (score 0):

It has no height.

That would be the first thing I would change.

Install a height constraint, too.